# flex mobile live video streaming to flash media server

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, camera, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I'm building a flex mobile application that streams the device's live video to flash media server.I can't run such an application on the flash buider's  emulator because it doesn't emulate the camera and i don't have an android device to test my work on it.I wonder if using the NetConnection and NetStream classes with the device's camera will work as in a regular flex web application.I really need an advice from someone who tested those two classes(NetConnection and NetStream) with flex mobile.Any pointers or advices will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Even I am facing the issue. Here is the link to my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128645/flex-mobile-live-streaming

Answer (score 1):

**NetConnection and NetStream with Adobe AIR for Mobiles works exactly as how it works with a regular web application.**

However, some things have to be considered. Your mobile application should be developed on a "Landscape" mode. Since there is a bug with adobe such that the video stream gets rotated when you are sending the video stream from your front camera.

**[Bug Report](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30317)**

However, i am not recommending you to stop developing the application. This will be a good challenge though.

Comment: Thanks Shankar , i really appreciate your advice.Did you try to make  something similair to the app that i'm trying to make.If you did , is there any other advice you can tell me?

Comment: Yeah i did the app what you are trying to do. So it is not out of the box question. You try start to develop the application and i will be helping you here in SO. Everything can't be explained here. Keep working on your app and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Hi Shankar , i'm facing a little problem  while connecting to flash media server and the debugger shows the following error: argumenterror: error #2126: netconnection object must be connected.      Do you have any idea how to handle this error ? Thanks in advance.